# How do I expand a `pd.Series` of dataclass objects into a `pd.DataFrame` with fields as columns?

Tags: python, pandas, python-dataclasses

For the scenario below `foo_bar` is not very human-readable.

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class FooBar:
  foo: int
  bar: str

foo_bar = pd.Series([FooBar(1, 'a'), FooBar(2, 'b')], index=[100, 200])
```

```
100    FooBar(foo=1, bar='a')
200    FooBar(foo=2, bar='b')
dtype: object
```

How can I get

```
foo bar
0   1   a
1   2   b
```

?

The naive solution would be to call `pd.DataFrame(foo_bar)`.
However, this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both

```
pd.DataFrame(foo_bar.to_list(), index=foo_bar.index)
```

and

```
foo_bar.apply(dataclasses.asdict).apply(pd.Series)
```

work.